# Collapse border between table data and inner content

Tags: html, css

I need to collapse borders between td and table td content like html table collapses border between td and table.

Comment: Why do you think it's a hack to hide the inner table's border? Table borders only collapse with its own children cells, not with table cells that it happens to sit in.

Comment: I know, what I wanted to know is that can I tell the same thing to the table data. If you would see my real code you would understand. I have tables inside tabledata which have tables inside and so on. I have to hide them all borders manually.

Comment: Tables with tables inside "and so on"? Hrm. Well, you can put borders only on the outer one with something like `table {border:1px solid;} table table {border:none}`

Comment: Just hoped there is css attribute for table cell like border-collapse: collapse;

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the bottom border from the cells in the last row. Something like:

```
tr:last-child .inner {border-bottom:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I'm working with ASP I used the GridView OnPreRender event to remove the bottom border from the last row table data items.